# How to animate column movement in Bootstrap Grid?

Tags: bootstrap-4, css-transitions

I'm making a dynamic form. You can toggle and add more forms according to your needs. When you toggle a form, it appears / disappears instantly. I want a moving animation. When a new form appears, to push the others, and when it disappears, all of them to move to their place.

Here is a picture of my grid: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVtjT.jpg

You can see the 4 cards. That's what I'm trying to animate.

I've tried using CSS transition property, however, it still snaps the same way as before.

```
.move-anim {
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
   transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
}
```

The classes that I've used on the divs:
    row, col-md-6

Comment: Please add a minimal example that demonstrates the grid HTML and toggling columns

Answer (score 1):

```css
.blue {
  background: blue;
  padding: 15px
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
  padding: 15px
}

.red {
  background: red;
  padding: 15px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="col-md-12 blue animated  fadeInUp">
        <h1>Test1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, commodi?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="col-md-12 orange animated  fadeInUp">
        <h1>Test2</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, commodi?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="col-md-12 red animated  fadeInUp">
        <h1>Test3</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, commodi?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/justmemaarten/pen/zXVgjB) I made a example for you.

Note: I have used `animate.css` do not forget to include it (from [here](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)).

Comment: No one is obligated to leave a comment about why they downvotes. When you see an unexplained downvote, try to explain it yourself: edit your post to fix grammar and/or spelling mistakes, retest your code, reread the question to see if you have misunderstood something. Don't take it personally. We are all here to learn.

Comment: If you are constantly looking for errors in my grammar then you should better read an encyclopedia. I know I don't have to take it personally, but it's not nice to get downvotes every time when I try to help someone.

Comment: Being rude to people who try to offer advice isn't helpful and won't give you anything. If you are always getting downvotes, then you should spend more times with the post. A potential reason your post was downvoted may be that you have no explanation.

Comment: no explanation? I left the code with a code pen. I think this is sufficient explanation? During training, for example, you learn this first. HTML and css are the easiest languages ​​available. And I am not rude, if I would blacken you then I would indeed. And as you already said in your previous message, do not take it too personally